# Unresolved class: Main Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I literally JUST created a new project in my AS, and the error "Unresolved class: Main Activity". I don't understand why it has an error from the start.

This is my XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my MainActivity.java file.

```
package com.example.hotlash;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hotlash">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: A dot is required to be appended to the start of the `MainActivity` value in the `android:name` attribute of the `activity` tag of a manifest. E.g. `<activity android:name=".MainActivity">` vs `<activity android:name="MainActivity">`.

Answer (score 1):

@D. Park,

try to add a period before the activity name:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hotlash">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"> <!-- <--- here -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

You may either **specify full activity class name** including the package name, like so: `com.example.hotlash.MainActivity` or, **specify the activity name with the leading period**: `.MainAcitvity`. In the latter case, it's completed using the application package name as a prefix (see the `package` attribute in the root `manifest` element).

Keep in mind that if you put your acitivity in a different package (e.g. `com.example.hotlash.activity`), you would specify the name like so: `.activity.MainActivity`.

Comment: Please consider explaining how appending a dot actually solves the issue, instead of stating it as a matter-of-fact.

Comment: Thanks, I tried specifying full activity class name and it worked! Thank you so much